# scrapy hanging on api call which returns large JSON object

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am using scrapy to make API calls to walmart's open API. Everything functions as expected except for one call which returns hundreds of thousands of products worth of information in JSON format. The json is roughly 2GB and takes roughly 4 minutes to download using requests. I have changed the following settings to accommodate for file size and download time like so:

```
DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT = 420
DOWNLOAD_MAXSIZE = 3200000000
# left download warn size unaltered just to get some feedback and see at what point the process was hanging
```

But for some reason scrapy hangs like so:

```
2017-03-15 20:34:23 [scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.http11] WARNING: Received more bytes than download warn size (33554432) in request <GET http://api.walmartlabs.com/v1/feeds/clearance?apiKey=XXXX>.
2017-03-15 20:34:47 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-03-15 20:35:47 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-03-15 20:36:47 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
^C2017-03-15 20:51:18 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Received SIG_SETMASK, shutting down gracefully. Send again to force 
^C2017-03-15 21:09:36 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Received SIG_SETMASK twice, forcing unclean shutdown
```

If you notice above, I stop getting on the minute INFO level stat logging after the first 3 minutes after the download size warning and repeated attempts to shut scrapy down do not work, I eventually had to kill the process manually (2 attempts at control-c did not do the job). If you notice the timestamps it took 17 minutes from the download size warning up to my first shutdown attempt. Yet the download timeout limit did not kick in.

Again, all other api calls (thousands of them) work without incident and this particular call works in about 4 minutes with requests library, and I have tried to disable download size limits as well as increase them but it still freezes with no other logging output (on debug level). Everything seems to indicate hanging while downloading and not making it to the callback. Any suggestions?

Comment: How did you make sure that the download was complete and (if so) the processing of the 2 GB JSON file not took longer than the time you've waited?

Is there any way to split up the Request in multiple ones, each returning a smaller dataset?

Comment: You should print something right when your callback function starts to determine if what's hanging is the downloading of the file or the parsing of it.

Comment: @rfelten everything I have stated above leads me to believe that it hangs during the download. The fact that on the minute stat logs stop after 3 minutes leads me to believe that it freezes/hangs roughly 3 minutes into the download and never makes it into the callback.

Comment: @Verbal_Kint Interesting. Can you do a small experiment? Download the file and feed it via an local webserver ( `python3 -m http.server ` ) to Scrapy. How is the CPU / RAM load changing  with respect to the console output?